# Iterate through list elements from grails in jasper report

Tags: grails, jasper-reports, jasper-plugin

I don't know how to render a list attribute from Grails in a jasper report

My domain class looks like this:

```
class Project {


String name
String projectLeader
List divisions

String toString(){
    "$name"
}


static hasMany = [divisions : Division ]
...
```

And the division domain class comes here

```
class Division {

String name
String divisionResponsible
String createDate

...
```

The project controller looks like this

```
class ProjectController {


def scaffold = true

def index = {
    redirect(action : list)
}


def createReport = {

    def projectreport = Project.getAll([params.project_id])
    chain(controller:'jasper',action:'index',model:[data:projectreport],params:params)

}
```

}

Displaying the data from the project domain works fine by defining and accessing the elements like this

```
$F{name}
$F{projectLeader}
```

The problem is accessing the list elements. The only working way I found was

```
 $F{divisions.[0].name}
```

or for the second element in the list

```
 $F{divsions.[1].name}
```

But this is only working if the number of list elements is everytime the same and limited.

Is there a way to iterate through the list elements, if the number of elements is not known?

Or is there a different possibility to access the list elements?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't need the index of list there.
Use like this:

```
<textFieldExpression   class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{divisions.name}]]></textFieldExpression>
```

rather than this:

```
 $F{divisions.[0].name}
```